# Magento Set Multiple Currencies

Tags: magento

I have a problem with Magento currency: My code is working fine otherwise, now I want to redirect the page after a change of currency.

Suppose my current URL is `http://www.example.com/women/?color=black`.

Now, When I change currency it will redirect to: `http://www.example.com/women/`; so it removes `?color=black`.

Code:

```
if($this->getCurrencyCount()>1): ?>
<div class="block block-currency">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Select Your Currency') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <select name="currency" title="<?php echo $this->__('Select Your Currency') ?>" onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>"<?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;
```

Updated Code:

```
<?PHP $currentParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams(); ?>
<div style="float:left; margin-top:10px; color:#727478;">
    <!--Change 1 to 0 if you wish to output selector always-->
    <?php if($this->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
    <span>Select Currency:</span>

    <select name="custom-currency-selector" id="custom-currency-selector">
    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): 
                $currencyUrl = $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code);
                foreach ($currentParams as $_param) {
                    $currencyUrl = $this->helper('core/url')->addRequestParam($currencyUrl, $_param);
                }
                ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $currencyUrl; ?>"
            <?php if($_code == $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                selected="SELECTED"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_code ?>
        </option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   </select>
  <?php endif;?>
```

Updated Code:

```
 <!--Change 1 to 0 if you wish to output selector always-->
    <?php if($this->getCurrencyCount() > 1): 
    $currentParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    ?>
    <span>Select Currency:</span>
    <select name="custom-currency-selector" id="custom-currency-selector">
    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name):
    $currencyUrl = $this->helper('core/url')->addRequestParam($this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code),$currentParams)
     ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $currencyUrl ?>"
            <?php if($_code == $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                selected="SELECTED"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_code ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add these params to the new url:

```
$currentParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$currencyUrl = $this->helper('core/url')->addRequestParam(
    $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code), 
    $currentParams
)
```

Then use $currencyUrl as url for redirect.

Comment: Maybe you use it in wrong place. What url contains $currencyUrl after the piece of code suggested by me?

Comment: yes i have alert value of  $currencyUrl;
value of $currencyUrl is http://122.170.114.91:90/fashionsouk.com/index.php/directory/currency/switch/currency/PKR/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEyMi4xNzAuMTE0LjkxOjkwL2Zhc2hpb25zb3VrLmNvbS9pbmRleC5waHAvYnktd29tZW4,/?&

Comment: You should check the JS which is processing redirect. Seems like it doesn't use the url from option value.

Comment: I have use onchange="setLocation(this.value)" in <select but it's not working.

Comment: You mean it doesn't redirect anywhere?

Comment: http://122.170.114.91:90/fashionsouk.com/index.php/by-women/?filter=&p=2
Please check this you will get idea.
In top left there is a dropdown for currency switcher

Comment: http://122.170.114.91:90/fashionsouk.com/index.php/by-women?filter[]=40

i done same. please check now.. my URL

Comment: It's fixed.
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php

in protected function _getRefererUrl()

$currentParams = $_GET;
$currencyUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->addRequestParam($refererUrl,$currentParams);
return $currencyUrl."";